# How to filter file input by file name

Tags: html, file

Can I use filter for `<input type="file" accept=""/>` with file name prefix/suffix ? For example for '_32' suffix will filter files from Fig-A to Fig-B.

Fig-A
[image]

Fig-B 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

No.

The accept attribute only accepts MIME types and file extensions.

It cannot match on other parts of the filename.

---

You could use JavaScript to read the filename and show an error if poor choice of file is selected.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener("input", function () {
    if (this.files[0].name.match(/_32\..{3,4}$/)) {
        console.log("OK");
    } else {
        console.log("Not OK");
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: Dear @Quentin, Filter should workable at the time of opening of the choosing window. No event need after clicking on the file. e.g. `a_cat.txt`, `b_cat.txt`, `a_mat.txt`, `b_mat.txt` need to filter by `cat` or `mat` on choosing window open.

Comment: @Mr.Mak — I refer you back to the first word of this answer. Checking afterwards is the best you can do.